# How to fix issue when PHP insert API runs successfully but no data is being inserted in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, json, api, pdo

I have **PHP API** for data insert, which Im testing on Postman. When I run this API, it gives me success msg on Postman but **No data is inserted** in **mysql** DB.
I studied All **similar/duplicate questions** but some of them miss a comma or some had a **NOT NULL** column in DB, But I dont have any such case, and still my data is not being inserted. please help me!

here is **part_order_details.php:**

```js
<?php

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost/Auth/");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");

include_once '../config/database.php';
include_once '../objects/order.php';

$database = new Database();
$db = $database->getConnection();

$order = new Order($db);

$a = file_get_contents("php://input");
$data = json_decode($a, true);

if($order->orderDetails($data)) {
    http_response_code(200);
    echo json_encode(array("message" => "All rows of Order Details are inserted successfully" ));
} else {
    http_response_code(400);
    echo json_encode(array("message" => "Sorry! Error while inserting rows of order details"));
}
?>
```

and order.php :

```js
<?php
class Order{
    private $conn;
    public $SparePartID;
    public $OrderID;
    public $Price;
    public $Quantity;
    public $qty;

    public function __construct($db){
        $this->conn = $db;
    }

    function orderDetails($arr)
    {
       $query=  "INSERT INTO sparepartorderdetails (SparePartID, OrderID, Quantity, Price) VALUES  (:SparePartID, :OrderID, :qty, :Price) ";
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

        foreach($arr as $item)
        {
            $stmt->bindValue(':SparePartID', $item['SparePartID']);
            $stmt->bindValue(':qty', $item['qty']);
            $stmt->bindValue(':Price', $item['Price']);
            $stmt->bindValue(':OrderID', $item['OrderID']);

            $stmt->execute();
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

And I am sending data on **Postman** like this below and getting **success** response.

```html
{
    "0": {
        "SparePartID": "36",
        "qty": "888",
        "Price": "88",
        "OrderID": "46"
    },
    "1": {
        "SparePartID": "35",
        "qty": "99",
        "Price": "0909",
        "OrderID": "46"
    }
}
```

Comment: Without digging too deep, may we assume that the `return true` statement in your loop is something you stuck in for debugging? right now you will always get success back, even if there was a database error. Try checking for an error on the db call and returning that instead.